# Using Asp.net MVC 5 with RabbitMQ and SignalR

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, rabbitmq, signalr

I have an asp.net MVC 5 application. Now I want to have a new feature allow me to receive GPS signal from devices and update devices real time in web client side.
My plan is to use RabbitMQ to handle message queue and SignalR to notify clients for postion update
My code in Rabbit consumer console application like this

```
var client = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>().Clients;
using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            {
                using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
                {
                    var queueName = channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName;
                    channel.ExchangeDeclare("mychannel", "fanout");
                    channel.QueueBind(queueName, "mychannel", "");
                    var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
                    consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
                    {
                        var body = ea.Body;
                        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                        Console.WriteLine("[x] Receive {0}", message);
                        client.All.hello(message);

                    };

                    channel.BasicConsume(queue: queueName,
                        autoAck: true,
                        consumer: consumer);
                    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to quit");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
```

But the code is not fired when I produce a message to RabbitMQ. If I remove code of signalR client:

```
var client = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>().Clients;
```

things work as expected and I can receive message as usual

My question is:

1. Is my approach correct
2. if the approach correct then how to make it work?

Many thanks

Comment: What did you find when you debugged the code?